# Creating tensorflow dataset with sparse matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

My dataset is a sparse matrix, and I'm trying to feed it using `tf.dataset`. My code below works for small matrixes, but for large matrixes (large number of columns), it fails with `ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.` I understand that this is because `tf.SparseTensor` creates a lot of `tf.constant` operations. What is the right way to feed a sparse matrix into a `tf.dataset` without converting it to a `SparseTensor`?

```
data_tensor = tf.SparseTensor(
    indices=[[0,0], [0,4], [1,1], [1, 50]],
    values=np.ones(4, dtype=np.float32),
    dense_shape=(2, 100)
)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_tensor)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
input_ph = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(iterator.get_next())
sum_op = tf.reduce_sum(input_ph)
sess.run(sum_op)
```